# JTextPane - auto wrap inserted JLabel components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextpane

I have JTextPane where I have inserted 20 components (JLabels). Unfortunately all the labels are on a single line.

How can I enforce that the JTextPane will automatically wrap the inserted objects?

[image]

```
package texteditor;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class JTextPaneExample extends JPanel {

    private JTextPane tp;

    public JTextPaneExample() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        tp = new JTextPane();
        tp.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(tp);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            JLabel lbl = new JLabel("AAAA ");
            lbl.setOpaque(true);
            lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
            tp.insertComponent(lbl);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GoBoard");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextPaneExample());
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JTextPane wraps on spaces. Your Document doesn't have any spaces so there is nothing to wrap on. You can add a space between labels:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("AAAA ");
    lbl.setOpaque(true);
    lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
    tp.insertComponent(lbl);
    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), " ", null);
    tp.setCaretPosition(doc.getLength());
}
```

Also, still not sure why you are using a JTextPane for this. You can just use a JPanel and have the components on the panel wrap to the next line. See [Wrap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) for a solution using this approach.

This should also make the solution from your last question ([JTextPane - get component values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36662110/jtextpane-get-component-values))  easier since you will be dealing with real components you won't need to search the Document to get the clicked label.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a `LayoutManager`, and in this case, you may want to / have to build your own LayoutManager (I had to do this for a similar problem years ago). In your LayoutManager layoutComponent method, check the index of the label and the length of all preferredsize.width / size.width of all components before that. If this is greater than your JTextPane preferredsize.width / size.width, move it to the next line.

Comment: Adding the `JTextPane` to a container using a `BorderLayout` and then adding that to the `JScrollPane` "should" have the desired effect (at least it has for me in the past)

Comment: I would be curious to see your final solution. Please post in in the forum. I have never seen a layout manager used in a JTextPanel. If you are using a layout manager in a JTextPane I question why you are even using a JTextPane. Seems like a strange solution to me.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I guess I'm out to lunch on this question. I don't understand the answer or your suggestion. I have used your approach to `"prevent"` wrapping in the past. See [No Wrap Text Pane](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/). When I use my suggestion (which does wrap) and then add your suggestion there is no wrapping.

Comment: Okay, I'm getting my tips mucked around, but `JTextPane` isn't controlled by a layout manager and I'd still think there are better ideas, of course, if you can provide a runnable example, it might clearify what you mean